# HTML/CSS Responsive Help Needed

Tags: html, css

Hello for some reason on Mobile (when you mess with the browser), my image on the left hand side seems to disappear on my page. I really am not sure what's going on with that or why that could be happening? I thought I did a pretty decent job with this.

Image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vNp5.png

HTML:

```
<div class="aboutus">

<div class="circular"></div>

<p class="aboutuspage"><font size="5" style="font-family: 'Oswald', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;">Bob Saggot</font><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vulputate neque at tortor scelerisque mollis. Mauris ultricies elit eget tortor elementum, quis feugiat odio venenatis. Nulla consequat orci at nulla hendrerit, eu consectetur ligula fringilla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed in ipsum tincidunt, tincidunt diam eget, aliquam tellus. Aenean metus ipsum, dapibus sit amet convallis non, aliquam quis mauris. Etiam suscipit massa nisl, id molestie tortor luctus nec. Quisque sit amet sodales massa. Donec posuere ultricies nisi, non pretium libero.</p>

</div>
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
<div class="aboutus">

<div class="circular"></div>

<p class="aboutuspage"><font size="5" style="font-family: 'Oswald', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;">Bob Saggot</font><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vulputate neque at tortor scelerisque mollis. Mauris ultricies elit eget tortor elementum, quis feugiat odio venenatis. Nulla consequat orci at nulla hendrerit, eu consectetur ligula fringilla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed in ipsum tincidunt, tincidunt diam eget, aliquam tellus. Aenean metus ipsum, dapibus sit amet convallis non, aliquam quis mauris. Etiam suscipit massa nisl, id molestie tortor luctus nec. Quisque sit amet sodales massa. Donec posuere ultricies nisi, non pretium libero.</p>

</div>
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
<div class="aboutus">

<div class="circular"></div>

<p class="aboutuspage"><font size="5" style="font-family: 'Oswald', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;">Bob Saggot</font><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vulputate neque at tortor scelerisque mollis. Mauris ultricies elit eget tortor elementum, quis feugiat odio venenatis. Nulla consequat orci at nulla hendrerit, eu consectetur ligula fringilla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed in ipsum tincidunt, tincidunt diam eget, aliquam tellus. Aenean metus ipsum, dapibus sit amet convallis non, aliquam quis mauris. Etiam suscipit massa nisl, id molestie tortor luctus nec. Quisque sit amet sodales massa. Donec posuere ultricies nisi, non pretium libero.</p>

</div>
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
<div class="aboutus">

<div class="circular"></div>
<p class="aboutuspage"><font size="5" style="font-family: 'Oswald', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;">Bob Saggot</font><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vulputate neque at tortor scelerisque mollis. Mauris ultricies elit eget tortor elementum, quis feugiat odio venenatis. Nulla consequat orci at nulla hendrerit, eu consectetur ligula fringilla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed in ipsum tincidunt, tincidunt diam eget, aliquam tellus. Aenean metus ipsum, dapibus sit amet convallis non, aliquam quis mauris. Etiam suscipit massa nisl, id molestie tortor luctus nec. Quisque sit amet sodales massa. Donec posuere ultricies nisi, non pretium libero.</p>

</div>
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
<div class="aboutus">

<div class="circular"></div>
<p class="aboutuspage"><font size="5" style="font-family: 'Oswald', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;">Bob Saggot</font><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vulputate neque at tortor scelerisque mollis. Mauris ultricies elit eget tortor elementum, quis feugiat odio venenatis. Nulla consequat orci at nulla hendrerit, eu consectetur ligula fringilla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed in ipsum tincidunt, tincidunt diam eget, aliquam tellus. Aenean metus ipsum, dapibus sit amet convallis non, aliquam quis mauris. Etiam suscipit massa nisl, id molestie tortor luctus nec. Quisque sit amet sodales massa. Donec posuere ultricies nisi, non pretium libero.</p>

</div>
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
<div class="aboutus">

<div class="circular"></div>
<p class="aboutuspage"><font size="5" style="font-family: 'Oswald', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;">Bob Saggot</font><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vulputate neque at tortor scelerisque mollis. Mauris ultricies elit eget tortor elementum, quis feugiat odio venenatis. Nulla consequat orci at nulla hendrerit, eu consectetur ligula fringilla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed in ipsum tincidunt, tincidunt diam eget, aliquam tellus. Aenean metus ipsum, dapibus sit amet convallis non, aliquam quis mauris. Etiam suscipit massa nisl, id molestie tortor luctus nec. Quisque sit amet sodales massa. Donec posuere ultricies nisi, non pretium libero.</p>

</div>
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
<div class="aboutus">

<div class="circular"></div>
<p class="aboutuspage"><font size="5" style="font-family: 'Oswald', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;">Bob Saggot</font><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vulputate neque at tortor scelerisque mollis. Mauris ultricies elit eget tortor elementum, quis feugiat odio venenatis. Nulla consequat orci at nulla hendrerit, eu consectetur ligula fringilla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed in ipsum tincidunt, tincidunt diam eget, aliquam tellus. Aenean metus ipsum, dapibus sit amet convallis non, aliquam quis mauris. Etiam suscipit massa nisl, id molestie tortor luctus nec. Quisque sit amet sodales massa. Donec posuere ultricies nisi, non pretium libero.</p>

</div>
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
<div class="aboutus">

<div class="circular"></div>
<p class="aboutuspage"><font size="5" style="font-family: 'Oswald', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;">Bob Saggot</font><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vulputate neque at tortor scelerisque mollis. Mauris ultricies elit eget tortor elementum, quis feugiat odio venenatis. Nulla consequat orci at nulla hendrerit, eu consectetur ligula fringilla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed in ipsum tincidunt, tincidunt diam eget, aliquam tellus. Aenean metus ipsum, dapibus sit amet convallis non, aliquam quis mauris. Etiam suscipit massa nisl, id molestie tortor luctus nec. Quisque sit amet sodales massa. Donec posuere ultricies nisi, non pretium libero.</p>

</div>
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
<div class="aboutus">

<div class="circular"></div>
<p class="aboutuspage"><font size="5" style="font-family: 'Oswald', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;">Bob Saggot</font><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vulputate neque at tortor scelerisque mollis. Mauris ultricies elit eget tortor elementum, quis feugiat odio venenatis. Nulla consequat orci at nulla hendrerit, eu consectetur ligula fringilla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed in ipsum tincidunt, tincidunt diam eget, aliquam tellus. Aenean metus ipsum, dapibus sit amet convallis non, aliquam quis mauris. Etiam suscipit massa nisl, id molestie tortor luctus nec. Quisque sit amet sodales massa. Donec posuere ultricies nisi, non pretium libero.</p>

</div>
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
<div class="aboutus">

<div class="circular"></div>
<p class="aboutuspage"><font size="5" style="font-family: 'Oswald', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;">Bob Saggot</font><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vulputate neque at tortor scelerisque mollis. Mauris ultricies elit eget tortor elementum, quis feugiat odio venenatis. Nulla consequat orci at nulla hendrerit, eu consectetur ligula fringilla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed in ipsum tincidunt, tincidunt diam eget, aliquam tellus. Aenean metus ipsum, dapibus sit amet convallis non, aliquam quis mauris. Etiam suscipit massa nisl, id molestie tortor luctus nec. Quisque sit amet sodales massa. Donec posuere ultricies nisi, non pretium libero.</p>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .aboutus:firstchild
{
   width: 984px;
   min-width: 984px;
   min-height: 56px;
   height: 56px;
   padding: 0 20px;
   text-align: left;

}
.circular 
{
    text-align: right;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    min-width: 250px;
    min-height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 150px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 150px;
    background: url(http://cdn.bavotasan.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/desktop.jpg) no-repeat;
    }
p.aboutuspage
{
width: 500px;
min-width: 500px;
margin-left: 30%;
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. I don't see any "responsive" code (i.e. media queries) in your post. Please include all relevant code and, if possible, a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to help illustrate the issue.

Comment: css :first-child is valid. :firstchild is not. You're using font tags, inline styles, nbsp... maybe you should clean that all up before worrying about the images

Comment: Didn't you already just ask this question?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24921661/image-disappears-in-mobile-html-css

Comment: This is an exact copy of the question you asked that I linked above. Just because that question is not getting to much attention does not mean you re-ask it.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the image is set to float.  Because there isn't enough room to have both side-by-side, the image is hidden by the second element (the paragraph text).

I don't know what the page looks like exactly, but you could remove the float from .circular and add position:relative and display: inline-block to .circular and .aboutuspage